# Return a drawable res id in Android?

Tags: java, android, imageview, return

I want to return a res id with a name (example resID) like "R.drawable.example" from a function.
It should be used like that:

```
ExampleImageView.setImageResource(resID)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int foo() {
  return(R.drawable.example);
}

ExampleImageView.setImageResource(foo());
```